# react-native-system-notification NativeModule is undefined on apk release

Tags: android, notifications, react-native

I'm working on this app project where I need to schedule notifications based on a list of predefined texts.  Everything works fine on my dev environment, but when I build the APK release, they won't work.  Debugging further I found out the notifications are a NativeModule and it becomes `undefined` on the release.

This returns the module attributes on `react-native run-android` but `undefined` in the release:

```
console.log(React.NativeModules.NotificationModule);
```

This is the actual error that led me to it:

```
Notification
  .create({ attrs })
  .then((n) => console.log('Notification', n)
  .catch((err) => console.log(err);
```

Prints:

```
{ [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'd.rGetApplicationName')] line: 670  column: 2663, sourceURL: 'index.android.bundle' }
```

I'm using react-native-system-notification with what I understand is an unrelated modification that [removes the GCM requirement](https://github.com/lainventoria/react-native-system-notification/commit/8dddaf0e498fce498a9e63fca9af98826d9386d3).

There's this [issue](https://github.com/neson/react-native-system-notification/issues/38) but the project seems inactive since August and the issue is from April.

So, where else should I look for to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've disabled proguard from the release and the notifications started to work!  No idea how to prevent proguard from messing with the package, but it was only saving 1Mb so I'm happy with this solution.

```
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
```

in `android/app/build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

I dug into their source--it looks good. Almost feels like a configuration error on your end. Go through their installation steps really carefully, and in the output of `./gradlew assembleRelease`, make sure you see it compiled/linked in the output. Also, make sure your React Native version is up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks!, I've checked them already several times and they are ok, the assembleRelease output seems ok, the package is mentioned many times during build, none of which are error messages.  I also compared the code to other modules and it seems ok as you say, but it's still missing in the release.